# Add a document to multiple folders (collections)

Tags: java, google-docs-api

I can insert a Google Document in a folder/collection using the Java API. But I would like to have this document in multiple folders. The method

```
public void addFolder(Person owner, java.lang.String folderName)
```

is deprecated. In the javadoc it refers to: `BaseEntry.addLink(Link)`.
I tried using that method as follows:

```
docEntry.addLink(DocumentListLink.Rel.PARENT, Link.Type.ATOM,
        folderEntry.getSelfLink().getHref());
```

This method does not work, I probably use the wrong parameters. 
So how can I link a document to multiple folders/collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here: http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/sample/docs/DocumentList.java

Inserting the document twice to different collections works using the code in the method below. I am still curious though why the addlink method fails for me.

```
  public DocumentListEntry moveObjectToFolder(String resourceId, String folderId)
      throws IOException, MalformedURLException, ServiceException, DocumentListException {
    if (resourceId == null || folderId == null) {
      throw new DocumentListException("null passed in for required parameters");
    }

    DocumentListEntry doc = new DocumentListEntry();
    doc.setId(buildUrl(URL_DEFAULT + URL_DOCLIST_FEED + "/" + resourceId).toString());

    URL url = buildUrl(URL_DEFAULT + URL_DOCLIST_FEED + "/" + folderId + URL_FOLDERS);
    return service.insert(url, doc);
  }
```